# How to start on QTP to automate a java swing application?

Tags: automated-testing, java, qtp

I have to start my automation on java swing application using QTP. I am quite a newbie in qtp.

All I need is some documentation of the TOOL on how to get things configured and a step by step guide on how to start with the project set up in order to automate a swing application. Any help in this regard is appreciated.

I am not asking for spoon feeding but just some initial guidance through documentation or any link which has these details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you will need the QTP Java Add in to automate Java applications.

Next, look into [the QTP tutorials right here](http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/qtp-quicktest-professional-tutorial-1/), they are interacting with the Flight application that is delivered with the QTP installation. The tutorial will give you a basic understanding of QTP, but skip the VBScript lessons on this site there are better ones. [W3Schools](http://w3schools.com/vbscript/default.asp) is not the best tutorial point, but they have a nice online "Try it yourself" feature.

When you have QTP installed there is also a documentation folder. The help function (F1) of QTP is also quite good and also based on examples on the Flight applications.

I was wondering, is there a special reason you would use QTP as a test automation tool for Swing, since there are cheaper (= free!) and maybe better alternatives [around the corner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91179/automated-tests-for-java-swing-guis).

Answer (score 0):

When you are starting out as a beginner in QTP, may be the best way to learn is to dive right in and explore.

First start off by learning about how object spy and object repository works in QTP. Then create an object repository and add different kind of objects like a JavaTextField, JavaTable, JavaTree, JavaStaticText, JavaButton. Now drag drop these objects one by one into your test and use the intelli-sense by pressing the ctrl-space. Now you can see what all the methods you have to perform the required task you want to do. If you have doubt on how to use those methods you can use F1 for QTP Help, this is the best possible source for you to learn about any non-Web related add-ins like Siebel,SAP,Java,VB etc;